# Text center not working in ReactJS with Foundation

Tags: reactjs, zurb-foundation

I am using Foundation library.
I want to center a div in ReactJS and I am unable to achieve it.

This is a working example in plain vanilla : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqdzZR

```
<div class="vertical grid-block">
<div class="grid-block text-center"><span>Hi there !</span></div>
<div class="grid-block text-center">
    <a class="button" href="#">Test Button</a>
</div>
```

But, this does not work with ReactJS :

```
var React = require('react');

var Comp = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
        return (<div className="grid-frame">
                <div className="vertical grid-block">
            <div className="grid-block text-center"><span>Instructions to login</span></div>
            <div className="grid-block text-center">
                <a className="button" href="#">Login with Facebook</a>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>);
  }
});

module.exports = Comp;
```

In the above component, the button has the styling indicating that the Foundation css styling is working.But the div is not centered for some reason.

So, the question is how do I center a div in a ReactJS component using the Foundation library ?

Answer (score 1):

```
return (<div class="grid-frame">
```

Should be className?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I have updated the question. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Inspect the DOM and check whether classes are defined at all.
You may be missing the stylesheet or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Check my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/

Maybe you forgot to add normalize.css?

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (<div className="grid-frame">
                <div className="vertical grid-block">
            <div className="grid-block text-center"><span>Instructions to login</span></div>
            <div className="grid-block text-center">
                <a className="button" href="#">Login with Facebook</a>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>);
    }
});

React.render(<Hello name="World" />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if React is changing the display property for the button?
Display inline-block can be horizontally centered with text align center. Display block works with margin: 0 auto;